# A new column in pandas that depends on values of the other rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I have an example data as:

```
column1 column2 column3 column4
  0.       1.      1.      0
  1.       1.      1.      1
  0.       0.      0.      0
  1.       1.      1.      0
  1.       1.      1.      1
```

I would like to create a new column(output) which shows 1 if at least one of the row values of the dataframe is 1, and 0 if the rows are all 0.

The output should look like this:

```
column1 column2 column3 column4. output
  0.       1.      1.      0.     1
  1.       1.      1.      1.     1
  0.       0.      0.      0.     0
  1.       1.      1.      0.     1
  1.       1.      1.      1.     1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for test if match at least one match:

```
df['output'] = df.eq(1).any(axis=1).astype(int)
#alternative
df['output'] = np.where(df.eq(1).any(axis=1), 1, 0)

#if only 0,1 values is possible use
#df['output'] = df.any(axis=1).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df['output'] = np.any(df.eq(1)., axis = 1).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check that the sum of the all columns in the row is superior to 0

`df.output = df.apply(lambda row: int(row.sum() > 0), axis=1)`